# Understanding the bitwise OR of SWT Constants

Tags: java, swt, constants, bitwise-operators

I'm examining some SWT code and I'm having trouble understanding how the SWT constants work and particularly, how their bitwose OR works.

For example:

`final Table leftTable = new Table(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);`

I looked up `SWT.MULTI` in the [API](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/package-summary.html) and found that its value is `1<<1`. What does this mean? I did the same for `SWT.FULL_SELECTION` and found its value to be `13` (more understandable).

What does it mean to bitwise OR these? Is there a quick way to determine what the result is? Why is it done this way?

Comment: If you don't know what `1 << 1` means, I'd rather recommend to take a look at a Java tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a complete list of the style bits [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/SWT_Widget_Style_Bits) and an excellent explanation [here](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/01/25/swt-style-bits/) and a general explanation on bitwise operators [here](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/bitops.html).

`<<` is the left bit shift operator as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

---

Let's make an example:

Assuming you have two style bits:

```
SWT.FOO = 4  // 100 binary
SWT.BAZ = 2  // 010 binary
```

If you now give `SWT.FOO | SWT.BAZ` to the `Table`, the result will be:

```
   100
OR 010
   ---
   110 // 6 in decimal
```

The table now wants to find out if you selected `SWT.BAZ`. It can do so by checking the following:

```
int styleBit = 6; // 110 binary

if((styleBit & SWT.BAZ) == SWT.BAZ)
{
    System.out.println("SWT.BAZ selected");
}
```

You can verify this calculation [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=BitAnd%5bBitOr%5b100%2C+010%5d%2C+100%5d+%3D%3D+100).